# Rows are lost when reading this tab-separated file with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quoting

I have a `.text` file with following format, where fields (index number, name and message) are separated by `\t` (tab-separated):

```
712 ben     Battle of the Books
713 james   i used to be in TOM
714 tomy    i was in BOB once
715 ben Tournaments of Minds
716 tommy    Also the Lion in the upcoming school play
717 tommy   Can you guess
718 tommy    P
...
```

which I read with `read_csv` into a data frame:

```
 chat = pd.read_csv("f.text", sep = "\t", header = None, usecols = [2])
```

But the data frame just has `9812` rows while the ordinary file has more than `12428` rows (just 21 empty lines). It is quite weird. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a download link to your data, difficult to answer here without posting guesses which is counter-productive

Comment: Very weird. Maybe is necessary parameter `lineterminator` of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Or you can try add `index_col=None`.How you check  length of `df` ? By `print len(df)` ?

Comment: @jezrael just `print df` It will show the row number under the table. Same result with `len(df)`

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. If you omit `usecols`, `length` is still wrong?

Comment: @jezrael yes. when i print line by line, I got `12428` lines.

Comment: Hmmm, try skip rows like `chat = pd.read_csv("f.text", skiprows=9810, sep = "\t", header = None, usecols = [2])`, then maybe check columns `print df.columns` and index `print df.index`

Comment: @jezrael And I got the remaining rows! What happened!?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `quoting`:

```
import csv

chat = pd.read_csv("f.text",sep = "\t", header = None, usecols = [2], quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: jezrael can you actually explain why this works, i.e. why the unquoted read dropped lines? Otherwise it's not a reusable resource to other users.

Comment: OMG, this saved me! It looks like the default behavior for read_csv() expects everything to be wrapped in quotes. But if it is a tab separated file with no quotes, then you need to specify such, otherwise the data parsing goes awry