# pandas: read_csv misses final lines

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv file which contains only numerical data, but not all of them are being read.

I'm calling it as follows:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', usecols=Settings.util_columns(), parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'], infer_datetime_format=True, low_memory=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print(f'Reading {file_name}')
print(df['TIMESTAMP'].min(), '|', df['TIMESTAMP'].max())
```

and it outputs the following:

```
Reading clean_data.csv
2008-12-03 20:30:00 | 2018-10-05 03:50:00
```

However, `clean_data.csv` (which is sorted by `'TIMESTAMP'`) contain TimeStamps up to 2019-08-27.

In addition to this, no warning nor error message is thrown/shown.

I found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598249/rows-are-lost-with-read-csv-in-pandas) from where I took the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, however it didn't change anything. Consider that my data is numerical.

Using:

- python==3.6.6
- pandas==0.25.1

**UPDATE**

My apologize, it was my fault. It turn out that the file which I was reading was not the one I was expecting to read.

Once again, I'm sorry, and thanks for your time.

Comment: By any chance, would you be able to share the csv? It's hard to help you if we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can share it, it's very large (gigabytes of data) :/

Comment: does `wc -l clean_data.csv` correspond to `len(df)+1`? (for Windows see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665718/3944322))

Comment: `len(df)` is 413992
`wc -l  clean_data.csv` is 455429

I'm working in linux, but the files were generated in windows

Comment: Could you show us, results of command `tail <your-file>`?